# Scattered Objects not visible in final render / Grasswald GScatter

Tags: rendering

Got a quite big blender scene with scattered Objects. Everything correct an visible in the Viewport but the output render is missing most of the scattered objects. Some are visible, most not. Its not the camera icon in the outliner, something else.

Got the scene here, feel free to try.

https://we.tl/t-iHSWBh6OyI

Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: As DFR said, add screenshots. But also, please use blend-exchange.com to transfer blend files. I don’t recognize the name We.tl, and I don’t immediately trust a company with such an odd and abbreviated name.

Comment: I agree to add a few screenshots that show the problem. We.tl is https://www.WeTransfer.com. It's a file hoster for (large) files. That's fine. But not everyone can download a 512 MB blend file to have a look and help you or to check if the question is relevant for them.

Comment: I don't know the Grasswald addon but do you really need 24000(!) objects in the scene? It's too many for my computer. For performance, it would be better to use instances with the particle system or Geometry Nodes.